# Element-wise in-operator between two arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm wondering if there is a nice and elegant way to do an element-wise in comparison between two arrays.

```
arr1 = [[1, 2], 
        [3, 4], 
        [5, 6]]

àrr2 = [3,
        5, 
        6]

result = arr2 in arr1
```

Now I want a result like :

```
[False, False, True]
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: I'm sorry, my example was a bit misleading. I want this to be performed element-wise, meaning I want to check, whether arr2[0] is in arr1[0], arr2[1] is in arr2[1] and so on.. I updated the example

Also the real arrays are much larger, so I would like to do it without loops

Answer (score 5):

You can use `operator.contains`:

```
>>> arr1 = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]
>>> arr2 = [3, 4, 7]
>>> list(map(contains, arr1, arr2)
[False, True, True]
```

Or for `numpy` use `np.isin`

```
>>> arr1 = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]])
>>> arr2 = np.array([3, 4, 7])
>>> np.isin(arr2, arr1).any(1)
[False  True  True]
```

Comment: That NumPy one might be wrong. For `arr2 = np.array([3, 7, 4])`, would give us something that might not be what OP expects. From what I have understood, OP wants to check for each element in arr2 against each in arr1. Again OP needs to clarify, I would think.

Comment: It's what OP has in their question

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, there is the wonderful [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to do this:

```
In [16]: np.in1d(arr2, arr1)
Out[16]: array([False,  True,  True])
```

From the docs, this function does the following:

> Test whether each element of a 1-D array is also present in a second array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `print([any(x in arr2 for x in a) for a in arr1])`

Answer (score 2):

#### comprehension and `zip`

```
[a in b for a, b in zip(arr2, arr1)]

[False, False, True]
```

Comment: To Down Voter: What is wrong with this answer?  If I can correct a mistake, I'd like to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with a list comprehension

```
result = [arr2[i] in arr1[i] for i in range(len(arr1))]
```

Then you have

```
[False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way:

```
for i in zip(arr2,arr1): 
   print(i[0] in i[1])
```